# How to configure g-wan to use virtual hosts?

Tags: web-server, configuration, virtualhost, g-wan

Say I have a domain foo.com and a server accessible at 50.60.70.80. I have configured the DNS entries so that foo.com and www.foo.com point to 50.60.70.80. I have g-wan running on the web server. Now I want to host different web sites on foo.com and on www.foo.com.

According to the [documentation](http://gwan.ch/archives/gwan_linux.pdf) I have to configure a root host and optionally some virtual hosts. So I choose foo.com to be the root host. www.foo.com is a virtual host. My problems is that g-wan seems to ignore my virtual host. No matter whether I use foo.com or ww.foo.com g-wan always serves the foo.com content.

This is my g-wan "config":

```
/gwan/0.0.0.0_80/#movq.org
/gwan/0.0.0.0_80/$www.movq.org
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The G-WAN FAQs explain how it works: http://gwan.com/faq#listener

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I believe that the www. prefix is hard-coded as an alias already.

You should rather try with something like `secure.movq.org` (providing that your DNS records are set, and that the client will use this domain name as the "Host: xxx" HTTP header then it should work for you too).

To simplify things you can use the G-WAN `aliases` feature for different domain names serving a same site and the `virtual hosts` (or another listener) for different sites.